# SNHU Python 'Simon Says': compare two strings for equality character-wise, without using an index?

Tags: python

I was given a prompt to solve and was able to write code that passed, but my question is, is there a more simplified way I could write this without having to create a new named variable (s_index = 0)? The code works just fine but I'm not sure if I solved it the way I was expected to and am open to suggestions for improvement :)

- Please note that this section in the work book has us focusing on using continue and break within loops

"Simon Says" is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y)
and the user must repeat the sequence. Create a for loop that compares the two strings.
For each match, add one point to user_score. Upon a mismatch, end the game.

Sample output with inputs: 'RRGBRYYBGY' 'RRGBBRYBGY'
User score: 4

```
user_score = 0    
simon_pattern = input()    
user_pattern  = input()    
s_index = 0    

for letter in user_pattern:
    if letter == simon_pattern[s_index]:
        user_score += 1
        s_index += 1
    else:
        break

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Comment: Try to use *enumerate(user_pattern)*  to get both index, letter as a tuple.

Comment: Your spec is a little ambiguous: Simon always outputs a string of length-10, but the user string could be shorter (it could even be '' if the user didn't press anything before timeout). So you need to handle different-length strings.

Answer (score 0):

using functions to encapsulate small specific parts of your logic is often helpful

```
def do_score(user_pattern="1234",simon_pattern="1235"):
    # using enumerate you can get the indices
    for s_index,a_char in enumerate(simon_pattern):
        if s_index >= len(user_pattern) or a_char != user_pattern[s_index]:
           # the index should always match the "sum" so no need to track or compute the sum
           return s_index
    return len(simon_pattern)
```

this method takes 2 strings and "scores" them based on the "simon_pattern" returning the score

then just

```
print(do_score(user_entered_input,simon_pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite this to this way: (this way you can completely eliminate the variable index, and simon_pattern[index] to get the letter)

Note - in Python a word is just a *sequence* of character/letters, you can iterate it directly, no need to use index.

```
simon = 'RRGBRYYBGY' 
user  = 'RRGBBRYBGY' # User score: 4
user_score = 0    


for user_char, simon_char in zip(user, simon):
    
    if user_char == simon_char:  # continue to check/and match...
        user_score += 1
      
    else:                        # break, if no match! 
        break

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, you never need to know the index or index into the strings, you can just use `zip()` to combine tuples of respective characters from the two (possibly different-length) strings:

```
def do_score(user_pattern='RRGBRYYBGY', simon_pattern='RRGBBRYBGY'):
    score = 0
    for uc,sc in zip(user_pattern, simon_pattern):
        if uc == sc:
            score += 1
        else:
           break
    return score

assert do_score('', '') == 0
assert do_score('RRG', '') == 0
assert do_score('', 'RRG') == 0
assert do_score('RRG', 'RRGB') == 3
```